# C program to capitalize a word inside quotation marks

Tags: c

I need to build a function that gets an input and capitalizes only the first letter, doesn't print numbers, capitalizes after a `.` for a new sentence, and capitalizes all words between a double quotation marks `"`.

This is what I got until now:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    char str[MAX] = { 0 };  
    int i;
    
    //input string
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str); //read string with spaces
    
    //capitalize first character of words
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        //check first character is lowercase alphabet
        if (i == 0)
        {
            if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'))
                str[i] = str[i] - 32; //subtract 32 to make it capital
            continue; //continue to the loop
        }
        if (str[i] == '.')//check dot
        {
            //if dot is found, check next character
            ++i;
            //check next character is lowercase alphabet
            if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
            {
                str[i] = str[i] - 32; //subtract 32 to make it capital
                continue; //continue to the loop
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //all other uppercase characters should be in lowercase
            if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
                str[i] = str[i] + 32; //subtract 32 to make it small/lowercase
        }
    }
    
    printf("Capitalize string is: %s\n", str);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I cant find a way to remove all numbers from input and convert all lowercase to uppercase inside a `"` plus code for not printing numbers if user input them.

if I input

```
I am young. You are young. All of us are young. 
"I think we need some help. Please" HELP. NO, NO NO, 
I DO NOT 
 NEED HELP
WHATSOEVER. 
"Today’s date is 
 15/2/2021"... 
I am 18 years old, are you 20 years old? Maybe 30 years?
```

output:

```
I am young. You are young. All of us are young. 
"I THINK WE NEED SOME HELP. PLEASE" help. No, no no, 
i do not 
 need help 
whatsoever. 
"TODAY’S DATE IS 
 //"... 
I am years old, are you years old? maybe years?
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show some examples of input and expected vs. actual output

Comment: Your loop risks running off the end of the string, with the extra `++i`s

Comment: ok i edited it with example of expected input

Comment: @MichaelBaazov Curious, who or what text suggested putting an `s` in `"%[^\n]s"`?

Answer (score 1):

The C standard library provides a set of functions, [in `ctype.h`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/ctype_h.htm), that will help you

Of particular interest, would be:

- `isdigit()` - returns true if digit
- `isalpha()` - returns true if alphabet character
- `isalnum()` - returns true if alpha/numeric character
- `islower()` - returns true if lower case character
- `isupper()` - returns true if upper case character
- `tolower()` - converts character to lower case
- `toupper()` - converts character to upper case

So, for example, you could replace the test/modify with:

```
if ( islower( str[i] ) )
{
   str[i] = toupper( str[i] );
}
```

Pedantically, `islower()` and `toupper()` return an `unsigned int` but that's a separate matter...

Comment: im new to c how do i use the function?
like this toupper(str)?

Comment: The function take a single character (strictly, a character integer) and return either a character or a boolean (again, strictly, a character interger). Answer updated

Comment: its for a project im using,not allowed to use those,but i already got my function to uppercase the first letter in a sentance,only got to convert the lowercase to uppercase inside a "" and delete all numbers

Comment: I'm curious to know the rationale for "not allowed to use"?

Comment: *Pedantically, islower() and toupper() return an unsigned int but that's a separate matter...* not really: `islower()` and friends return an `int` by are only defined for arguments values `EOF` and all values of type `unsigned char`, which means why you should not write `islower( str[i] )` but `islower( (unsigned char)str[i] )`. Furthermore you do not need to test if a byte is lowercase to pass it to `toupper()`.

Comment: If `islower()` then `toupper()` will be in the appropriate range?!  But point taken... I was trying not to over-complicate the answer!

Comment: @Andrew: I agree to not complicate things, but your remark is incorrect. The test can be removed and `str[i] = toupper( (unsigned char)str[i] );` is fine. But without the cast, the code has undefined behavior on both `islower` and `toupper` for negative `char` values different from `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove letters from a string if you keep two indices, one for reading and one for writing. The following loop will remove all digits from a string:

```
int j = 0;          // writing index, j <= i
int i;              // reading index

for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
    int c = (unsigned char) str[i];

    if (!isdigit(c)) str[j++] = c;
}

str[j] = '\0';
```

(I've used to character classification functions from `<ctype.h>` mentioned in Andrew' answer.)

This is safe, because `j` will always be smaller or equal to `i`. Don't forget to mark the end of the filtered string with the nullterminator, `'\0'`. You can combine this filtering with your already existing code for replacing characters.

In your code, you capitalize letters only if they are directly behind a full stop. That's usually not the case, there's a space between full stop and the next word. It's better to establish a context:

- **shift**: capitalize the next letter (beginning or after full stop.)
- **lock**: capitalize all letters (inside quotation marks.)

When you read a letter, decide whether to capitalize it or not depending of these two states.

Putting the filtering and the "shift context§ together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "one. two. THREE. 4, 5, 6. \"seven\", eight!";

    int shift = 1;      // Capitalize next letter
    int lock = 0;       // Capitalize all letters
    int j = 0;          // writing index, j <= i
    int i;              // reading index
    
    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        int c = (unsigned char) str[i];
    
        if (isdigit(c)) continue;
        
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            if (shift || lock) {
                str[j++] = toupper(c);
                shift = 0;
            } else {
                str[j++] = tolower(c);
            }
        } else {
            if (c == '"') lock = !lock;
            if (c == '.') shift = 1;
            
            str[j++] = c;
        }
    }
    
    str[j] = '\0';
    
    puts(str);
    printf("(length: %d)\n", j);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will change `a., b` to `A., B`  which may of may not be expected.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove some characters, you should use 2 index variables: one for reading and one for writing back to the same array.

If you are allowed to use `<ctype.h>`, it is a much more portable and efficient way to test character types.

Also do not use `scanf()` with protection against buffer overflow. It is as bad as using `gets()`. Given the difficulty in specifying the maximum number of bytes to store into `str`, you should use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int main() {
    char str[MAX];  
    int i, j;
    unsigned char last, inquote;
    
    //input string
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) { //read string with spaces
        // empty file
        return 1;
    }
    
    last = '.';  // force conversion of first character
    inquote = 0;
    //capitalize first character of words
    for (i = j = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        unsigned char c = str[i];

        //discard digits
        if (isdigit(c)) {
            continue;
        }
        //handle double quotes:
        if (c == '"') {
            inquote ^= 1;
        }
        //upper case letters after . and inside double quotes
        if (last == '.' || inquote) {
            str[j++] = toupper(c);
        } else {
            str[j++] = tolower(c);
        }
        if (!isspace(c) && c != '"') {
            // ignore spaces and quotes for the dot rule
            last = c;
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';  // set the null terminator in case characters were removed
    
    printf("Capitalized string is: %s", str);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot friend ,helped me a lot,just to say you forgot to declare the J for the loop.

Comment: @MichaelBaazov: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.